# How to close bootstrap 5 modal with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5, react-dom

I am using bootstrap 5 with react in my project. I did not install it but using cdn links to use bootstrap element in the dom. I am using bootstrap modal to update data. After the update I want to close the modal. I tried to use useRef hook but it does not work and it is giving error. I tried to close it by document by id but still its not wroking. My code is

```
<div
          className="modal fade"
          id="QuestEditModal"
          tabIndex="-1"
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
          <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <h5 className="modal-title">Edit Question</h5>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn-close"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close"
                ></button>
              </div>

              <div className="modal-body">
                <div className="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
                  <div className="p-2 w-80 bd-highlight">
                    
                    <div className="input-group mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="Question" className="form-label">Question</label>
                        <textarea className="form-control" 
                        id="Question" rows="3" cols="160" name="question"
                        value={qcont}
                        onChange={(event) => handleQChange(event)}
                        ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-group mb-3">
                    <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-primary float-start"
                      onClick={(e) => handleSave(e)}>
                          Update
                    </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

const handleSave = (event) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:57030/api/question", {
         method: "PUT",
         headers: {
           Accept: "application/json",
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({
           QuestId:qid,
           ExamUid:exuid,
           QuestUid:quid,
           Content:qcont
         }),
       })
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(res => {
             console.log(res);
             refreshList();
           },
           (error) => {
             alert("Failed" + error);
           }
         ); 
  }
```

Comment: have you tried any of the suggested solutions? If yes please give feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The close button of modal has these parameters

```
<button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn-close"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close"
                ></button>
```

My save button was

```
<button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-primary float-start" onClick={(e) => handleSave(e)}>
                          Update
                    </button>
```

I have added two parameters of modal's close button to my save button and now it is not only saving the data but also closing the modal popup.

```
data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"
```

like this

```
<button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-primary float-start" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close" onClick={(e) => handleSave(e)}>
                          Update
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this.
Create ref for the model

```
  const modalRef = useRef(null);
```

```
    <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="QuestEditModal"
        ref={modalRef}
        tabIndex="-1"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >....</div>
```

Now After the successful API response create a model instance and close it.

```
const bootstrapModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalRef.current);
bootstrapModal.hide();
```

Check the we they did in the [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#passing-options)

As per the doc you can directly use the id without ref

```
const model= new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('QuestEditModal'));
model.hide();
```